# ASP.NET MVC: Model in strongly typed view not populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am brand spanking new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm working through a tutorial to get the basics.  The tutorial is in C# and I'm converting it to VB to stay consistent with some related projects.  I have to assume that I'm missing something in that conversion but can't figure out what it could be.

I have the following class:

```
Public Class GuestResponse
    Public Name As String
    Public Email As String
    Public Phone As String
    Public WillAttend As Boolean?
End Class
```

and a strongly-typed view related to that class:

```
@ModelType PartyInvites.GuestResponse

@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Using Html.BeginForm
        @<p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(Of String)(Function(x) x.Name)</p>
        @<p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(Of String)(Function(x) x.Email)</p>
        @<p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(Of String)(Function(x) x.Phone)</p>
        @<p>
            Will you attend?
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Of Boolean?)(Function(x) x.WillAttend,
                                                        New SelectListItem() {New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString},
                                                        New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString}}, "Choose an option")
        </p>
        @<input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
    End Using
</body>
</html>
```

My controller has a simple action method that takes that class and responds with another view:

```
<HttpPost>
Function RsvpForm(g As GuestResponse) As ViewResult
    'TODO: Email response to the party organizer
    Return View("Thanks", g)
End Function
```

Unfortunately, the form data from the post request isn't being populated in my GuestResponse class.  If I insert a breakpoint in that action method, all the GuestResponse properties are empty.  At the same time, the Request.Form values look as expected - they're just not filling in the GuestResponse object.

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you missing something on your `Html.BeginForm` -> `("Therequest", "Controller", method:= FormMethod.Post)`??

Comment: @RyanWilson The tutorial doesn't indicate any parameters for that.  I tried adding them explicitly and get the same result - object properties are still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<FromForm>` attribute to the `g` parameter.

Comment: I believe that attribute is ASP.NET Core specific.  Intellisense isn't recognizing it and I can't compile.

Comment: True, I thought you were using ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  Apparently, ASP.NET will only populate properties of an object - my object only had public fields.

So this:

```
Public Class GuestResponse
    Public Name As String
    Public Email As String
    Public Phone As String
    Public WillAttend As Boolean?
End Class
```

should be:

```
Public Class GuestResponse
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property WillAttend As Boolean?
End Class
```

Thanks to those of you who participated.